# org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I am new to hibernate and would appreciate any help.  The following code throws the above exception:

```
session.beginTransaction();
session.update(a);
if(!a.getState().equals(TransactionStatus.ACTIVE))
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: provide more code !!

Comment: Please provide more information , also what is the issue you are facing complete exception logs and what you have tried , what you are trying to do ..

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by wrapping my transaction in the following code:

```
try {
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        session.save(a);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
```